# Filter for combination of column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to filter for all People who have the same AttributValue for certain Attributs as another Person
I have the following Query:

```
SELECT
  p1.keyValue,
  p1.Displayname,
  p2.keyValue,
  p2.Displayname,
  p1.ImportantAttrName,
  p1.ImportantAttrValue
FROM Person p1 WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN Person p2 WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON p1.ImportantAttr = p2.ImportantAttr
WHERE p1.keyValue != p2.keyValue
AND p1.ImportantAttrValue = p2.ImportantAttrValue
```

with this query I will get all entries twice, because every Person will be in p1 and p2.
So the result will look like this:

```
I123    Freddy Krüger   A123    The Horsemen   Moviecategorie    Horror
A123    The Horsemen    I123    Freddy Krüger   Moviecategorie    Horror
```

But for analysis purposes it would be be nice if I could get a combination of p1.keyvalue and p2.keyvalue only once, without respect to in which of both colums the values are.

So far I did this by exporting to excel and do the cleanup there, but is there a way to fix the query to not get this "duplicates"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `where p1.keyValue < p2.keyValue`:

```
SELECT
    p1.keyValue,
    p1.Displayname,
    p2.keyValue,
    p2.Displayname, 
    p1.ImportantAttrName,
    p1.ImportantAttrValue
FROM Person p1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Person p2 WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON p1.ImportantAttr = p2.ImportantAttr
WHERE
    p1.keyValue < p2.keyValue AND       -- change is here
    p1.ImportantAttrValue = p2.ImportantAttrValue;
```

This will ensure that you do not see duplicate pairs.  To understand numerically why this works, consider two key values, `1` and `2`.  Using the condition `!=`, both `1-2` and `2-1` meet that criteria.  But using `<` results in only `1-2`.

Comment: arg facepalm...sometimes its really 'miss the forest for the trees' .... Thanks, I'll accept this answer since it also explains why this works

Answer (score 2):

You can turn:

```
on p1.ImportantAttr = p2.ImportantAttr
```

to:

```
on p1.ImportantAttr = p2.ImportantAttr and p1.keyValue < p2.keyValue
```

The whole query could look like this:

```
SELECT
  p1.keyValue,
  p1.Displayname,
  p2.keyValue,
  p2.Displayname,
  p1.ImportantAttrName,
  p1.ImportantAttrValue
FROM Person p1 WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN Person p2 WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON p1.ImportantAttr = p2.ImportantAttr
  AND p1.keyValue < p2.keyValue
WHERE p1.ImportantAttrValue = p2.ImportantAttrValue
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be different way of approach but can be get the expected.

Using Partition Count(*) :

```
select count(*) over(partition by Attr) as RepeatCount, * from (
select keyValue,DisplayName,ImportantAttr + ' ' +ImportantAttrValue as Attr
  from tblTest) tblTemp
```

as per the above Query you will get the result like below

```
> RepeatCount    keyValue     DisplayName          Attr
> 
> 1       P321        The Ironman          Generalcategorie Test 
> 2       I123        Freddy Krüger        Moviecategorie Horror 
> 2       A123        The Horsemen         Moviecategorie Horror
```

from this result you can filter records by Repeatcount > 1